# Nginx location block for pages and sub pages

Tags: nginx

I have a site set up running using nginx. I've installed a python service that runs web pages on port 4001. I'm trying to set up a location block in my nginx config file so I can view these pages at a specific url, without the port number. I set up the following block, which works to serve up one page:

```
location /test/ {
    proxy_pass http://example.net:4001/;
}
```

I need to have a block that will allow access to the main page as well as all sub pages:

/test/admin

/test/admin/objectdb

etc.

I can set up separate location blocks for each page, but that would be a crappy way of solving the problem, and the url is not always static. I've read through several posts that suggest the "/" at the end of the url is where the solution lies, as well as trying to use a regular expression to grab everything after /test/ and use that in the proxy_pass, but so far nothing has worked. I think I'm missing something simple here. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this figured out (mostly.) I managed to create a block that handles all the sub pages, but not the initial page. I then created a block specifically for the initial page. It now looks like this:

```
location /testmain {
    proxy_pass http://example.net:4001/;
}

location ~ ^/test/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://example.net:4001/$1/;
}
```